# Remove out of stock warning and continue shopping with remaining products

Tags: woocommerce, product, stock

I want to remove the out of stock warning from my woocommerce e.g
if I've 5 products in stock and user enter 10 to buy it will not show any warning and put the 5 products in the cart and continue shopping can we do this in woocommerce cause I'm searching from several hours but still find nothing any of you help me how can i do this ?

Comment: You should set backorders option in your products settings…

Comment: sorry i didn't get you ?

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-products/#section-22

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want but you can switch of the out of stock messages with a few clicks. In the back end go to:
Woocommerce > Settings > Products. Now  click on the blue link "Inventory"(its right below the tabs).
In the inventory screen, scroll down to 'Stock display format' and select the value "*never show quantity remaining in stock*"
Finish by clicking on "Save Changes".